Adding a dynamic average line to a line graph with multiple lines

I want to add a dynamic average line to the line graph in the top right. Would ideally adjust to whatever wellset I filter to. Adding a well count line that shows how many wells are contributing to the average would also be very helpful. Is there a way to just do this within the Spotfire platform?
I can't seem to create an average line for each x/y relationship amongst all the data that's actually showing in the plot. Not all of the background data that is currently not showing because it is filtered out.

I am struggling to see the details of your picture. Are you referring to the top-right plot? How is the plot structured? Are the lines different columns or different rows. What is a wellset vs well? Please give details to understand and reproduce the question.

Yes, it is a line graph with a filtered subset showing different y values for the same x. I would like to be able to create a line within the plot that updates as different filters are applied and averages the y value of every line for every x value. This will create an average line that has a different y for every x. When I say "wellset", it can refer to 10 or 100 different oil and gas wells with production data. I would like to be able to see the average line for whatever "wellset" I choose in the map chart.

The easiest way you can do this is by creating a second plot and removing the Line by. This would create an average of all your lines that responds to filters.

Not a bad idea! Thanks!
